# How to solve Method App\JenisSurat::__toString() must return a string value on Laravel 5?

Tags: php, database, input, laravel-5, crud

I want to input data to database. I am using Laravel 5. When I clicked the submit button. I got an error like the image below. Here is controller:
`

```
    public function tambahjenissurat(Request $request)
{       $this->validate($request, [
        'jenis_surat' => 'required'
    ]);

    $jenis_surat = $request['jenis_surat'];

    $jenis_surat = new JenisSurat();
    $jenis_surat->jenis_surat = $jenis_surat;

    $jenis_surat->save();

    return redirect()->route('jenissurat');
}`
```

[image]

Comment: `use JeniSurat;` at the top of your class

Comment: why have you given the object created `$jenis_surat = new JenisSurat();` and the variable assigned ` $jenis_surat = $request['jenis_surat'];` has same names?

Comment: did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is expecting a string but you are passing an object. that could be the problem. try to give different names for object and variable. Something like this should fix the problem. See the lines below EDIT sections

```
public function tambahjenissurat(Request $request)
{       $this->validate($request, [
    'jenis_surat' => 'required'
]);

**EDIT**

$jenis_surat_var = $request['jenis_surat'];

$jenis_surat = new JenisSurat();

**EDIT**
$jenis_surat->jenis_surat = $jenis_surat_var;

$jenis_surat->save();

return redirect()->route('jenissurat');
}
```